# How to use formatter?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, formatter

I'm following this example https://tahirnaushad.com/2017/09/03/formatters-in-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api/ in trying to create output for XML and JSON by appending `.xml` or `.json` to the end of the URL.

The example only talks about xml but I can't that working. Below is my code.

```
[Route("api/check")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpGet("/check1.{format}"), FormatFilter]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "testing check1";
    }
...
}
```

Accessing:

```
http://localhost/api/check/
```

returns the following as HTML:

> testing check1

http://localhost/api/check/check1.xml display a white page.

I have the following in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
        options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());

        options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat(
                                     "xml", "application/xml");
    });
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?